# Highcharts :Rendering only Percentage Bar Using type: 'xrange'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

want to render Percentage Bar without Toolchip,title,xAxis,etc.

should use x-range?

[Percentage Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw8Vx.png)

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series

Comment: Yes, you can use `x-range` or `columnrange` with additional customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use `x-range` series type. I have prepared a simple example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'xrange',
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        type: 'category'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
            y: 0,
            partialFill: 0.25
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }]
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lkyhfs4x/